# MySQL Left join - odd problem

Tags: mysql, join

Running mySQL Community Server 5.5.13

Using the following query:

```
select t1.f1, t2.f1, t2.f2
from t1 left join t2 on (t1.f3 = t2.f3)
```

If the left join finds no matches in table t2, rather than putting nulls in the values for t2.f1, t2.f2, it is actually putting the column names there.

Any suggestions why this might be happening?

Comment: Are you getting exactly one row of output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `t1`.`f1`, `t2`.`f1`, `t2`.`f2`
FROM `t1`
LEFT JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.`f3` = `t2`.`f3`;
```

Comment: Egg on my face.  Turns out it was corrupted data in t2, but thanks for the response.  Out of curiosity, is it a best practice to put the single quotes around the table and field names?

Comment: @jam, no it looks ugly and fluffy and nasty and horrible, the backticks are only for fields names that are reserved words, have spaces in them or are (gasp*) numbers.

Comment: @jam: They are not single quotes, but backticks `. YES, you will avoid many troubles by using them, such as using reserved words for/on your column names.

Comment: @Johan: LOOKING ugly, fluffy, nasty, or horrible is a different thing from avoiding troubles. Try naming a column `dropped_items`, and we will see how horrible it looks (for context).

Comment: @Shef, I don't like 'm for the very reason that they **allow** you to name a column a reserved word. And the sight of them makes me dizzy, it's like visual diarria. And yes this is a personal preference, I just believe papering over bad choose of column names with indiscriminate use of backticks is **not** best practise.